# CloudSearch Batch Update Takes > 60s

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

We've been experiencing problems where batch update requests take in excess of 60 seconds. We're updating a few kbs of data, quite some way short of the 5MB limit.

What is surprising me is not so much the time taken to index the data, but the time taken for the update *request* itself. Just uploading ~65kb of data can take over a minute.

We're making frequent updates with small quantities of data. Could it be that we're being throttled?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies to your problem, but [Amazon's documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/creatingsdf.html) recommends sending large batches if possible.

> Important
>   Whenever possible, you should group add and delete operations in batches that are close to the maximum batch size. Submitting a large volume of single-document batches to the document service can increase the time it takes for your changes to become visible in search results.

It talks about search result availability, but I don't think it's a stretch to say that this also would affect SDF processing performance.